# How to draw line between two points in JavaScript - Google Maps Api Route

Tags: google-maps, google-polyline

I have two points on the map, I was able to take the distance using the API, now I need to draw a line between the points so that the user sees all the way. I read that you need to use the polyline, but I unfortunately can not. I take the user's GPS coordinates as point A - and on the map, in the drag event I take the coordinates of point B. You can see an example on the following page: https://tojweb.tj/abb.php

Can you help?

I read that you need to use the polyline, but I unfortunately can not.

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
} else {
   console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
}


function showPosition(position) {
    document.getElementById('mypos_lat').value=position.coords.latitude;
    document.getElementById('mypos_lon').value=position.coords.longitude;

  //alert("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude);
}

var darection = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;


      function initialize() {



    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 13,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.583958, 68.780528),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      gestureHandling: "greedy",
      fullscreenControl: false,
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      zoomControl: true,
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
        darection.setMap(map);
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function() { 
        var centeral = map.getCenter();
            //alert(centeral);


        var names = centeral.toString();
        var names =names.substr(1);
        names = names.substring(0, names.length - 1);

        console.log(names);

        var re = /\s*,\s*/;
        var nameList = names.split(re);
                document.getElementById('bpos_lat').value=nameList[0];
                document.getElementById('bpos_lon').value=nameList[1];

                source_a = document.getElementById("mypos_lat").value;
                source_b = document.getElementById("mypos_lon").value;

                source_d = document.getElementById("bpos_lat").value;
                source_e = document.getElementById("bpos_lon").value;

                var darection = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
                var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;  


                //darection.setPanel(document.getElementById('panallocation'));

                source = source_a + "," + source_b;
                destination = source_d + "," + source_e;







                var request = {
                    origin: source,
                    destination: destination,
                    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
                    //Показ алтернативных дорог 
                    provideRouteAlternatives: true 
                };
                directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                        darection.setDirections(response);
                    }
                });

                var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
                service.getDistanceMatrix({
                    origins: [source],
                    destinations: [destination],
                    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
                    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
                    avoidHighways: false,
                    avoidTolls: false
                }, function (response, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK && response.rows[0].elements[0].status != "ZERO_RESULTS") {
                        var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
                        var duration = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text;



                        distancefinel = distance.split(" ");
                        //start_addressfinel = start_address.split(" ");
                    //  $('#distance').val(distancefinel[0]);
                        console.log(distancefinel[0]);


                        document.getElementById("distancesa").value = distancefinel[0];


                        ////////// IN THIS STATE I WANT DRAW LINE ///////////////////


                    } else {
                        alert("Unable to find the distance between selected locations");
                    }
                });
            } 
        );
    $('<div/>').addClass('centerMarker').appendTo(map.getDiv())
         //do something onclick
        .click(function(){
           var that=$(this);
           if(!that.data('win')){
            that.data('win',new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:'this is the center'}));
            that.data('win').bindTo('position',map,'center');
           }
           that.data('win').open(map);
        });
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Why do you think you cannot use the polyline ? Because you have coordinates as from/to points ?

Comment: I have latlon coordinates of points A and B, I tried to find information on how this is done, I used codes from different sources, but I always got an error. I asked for help at the last moment. Since I can’t do it myself.

Comment: The fact that you had an error doesn't mean you cannot use it, it just means you've been using it wrong. Please edit your question as to reflect what you have done and what error you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Directions Service](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Directions) of Google Maps JavaScript API to get the directions between 2 points and pass the DirectionsResult to the [DirectionsRenderer](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DisplayingResults), which can automatically handle the display in the map.

Here is the code I made which handles the use-case (Geolocating Point A, Draggable Marker B, then having a route between 2 points) from your description. You can also check it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gtz3jya8/).
Hope this helps!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <style>
        #map {
            height: 100%;
        }

        /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
        var map, infoWindow, markerA, markerB, drag_pos;

        function initMap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: {
                    lat: -34.397,
                    lng: 150.644
                },
                zoom: 6
            });
            markerA = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map
            });
            markerB = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map
            });
            infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
            var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
            var directionsRenderer1 = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                map: map,
                suppressMarkers: true
            });
            var directionsRenderer2 = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                map: map,
                suppressMarkers: true,
                polylineOptions: {
                    strokeColor: "gray"
                }
            });

            // Try HTML5 geolocation.
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                    var pos = {
                        lat: position.coords.latitude,
                        lng: position.coords.longitude
                    };

                    map.setCenter(pos);
                    map.setZoom(15);
                    //Put markers on the place
                    infoWindow.setContent('Your Location');
                    markerA.setPosition(pos);
                    markerA.setVisible(true);
                    markerA.setLabel('A');
                    markerA.addListener('click', function() {
                        infoWindow.open(map, markerA);
                    });

                    //Get new lat long to put marker B 500m above Marker A
                    var earth = 6378.137, //radius of the earth in kilometer
                        pi = Math.PI,
                        m = (1 / ((2 * pi / 360) * earth)) / 1000; //1 meter in degree

                    var new_latitude = pos.lat + (500 * m);
                    var new_pos = {
                        lat: new_latitude,
                        lng: position.coords.longitude
                    };

                    markerB.setPosition(new_pos, );
                    markerB.setVisible(true);
                    markerB.setLabel('B');
                    markerB.setDraggable(true);

                    //Everytime MarkerB is drag Directions Service is use to get all the route
                    google.maps.event.addListener(markerB, 'dragend', function(evt) {
                        var drag_pos1 = {
                            lat: evt.latLng.lat(),
                            lng: evt.latLng.lng()
                        };

                        directionsService.route({
                                origin: pos,
                                destination: drag_pos1,
                                travelMode: 'DRIVING',
                                provideRouteAlternatives: true
                            },
                            function(response, status) {
                                if (status === 'OK') {

                                    for (var i = 0, len = response.routes.length; i < len; i++) {
                                        if (i === 0) {
                                            directionsRenderer1.setDirections(response);
                                            directionsRenderer1.setRouteIndex(i);

                                        } else {

                                            directionsRenderer2.setDirections(response);
                                            directionsRenderer2.setRouteIndex(i);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    console.log(response);
                                } else {
                                    window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
                                }
                            });
                    });
                }, function() {
                    handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
                });
            } else {
                // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
                handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
            }
        }

        function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
            infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
            infoWindow.open(map);
        }
    </script>
    <!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for the time allotted for me. Can I get roads distance and time and show them in div?

Comment: You can get it using this `response.routes[i].legs[i].distance.text` and this  `response.routes[i].legs[i].duration.text` .

Here is a modified [code](https://jsfiddle.net/5Lkr7zuy/1/) that adds these function to the previous code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and support. Now I'm starting to understand how it works. Thanks you. Can you tell me how I can switch between alternative roads options?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code. The first commented code does not draw and does not produce any errors. The second code throws an error:
InvalidValueError: at index 0: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral with finite coordinates: in property lat: NaN is not an accepted value

I know that I am wrong and I am writing my code in the wrong place. I need help to show where the error is and how to fix it so that I understand.

```
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else {
   console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
  }


function showPosition(position) {
    document.getElementById('mypos_lat').value=position.coords.latitude;
    document.getElementById('mypos_lon').value=position.coords.longitude;

  //alert("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude);
}

var darection = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;











function initialize() {
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.583958, 68.780528),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    gestureHandling: "greedy",
    fullscreenControl: false,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    zoomControl: true,
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
darection.setMap(map);
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function() { 
var centeral = map.getCenter();
//alert(centeral);


var names = centeral.toString();
var names =names.substr(1);
names = names.substring(0, names.length - 1);

console.log(names);

var re = /\s*,\s*/;
var nameList = names.split(re);

document.getElementById('bpos_lat').value=nameList[0];
document.getElementById('bpos_lon').value=nameList[1];

source_a = document.getElementById("mypos_lat").value;
source_b = document.getElementById("mypos_lon").value;

source_d = document.getElementById("bpos_lat").value;
source_e = document.getElementById("bpos_lon").value;

var darection = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;  


//darection.setPanel(document.getElementById('panallocation'));

source = source_a + "," + source_b;
destination = source_d + "," + source_e;


var request = {
    origin: source,
    destination: destination,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    //Показ алтернативных дорог 
    provideRouteAlternatives: true 
};
                directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                        darection.setDirections(response);
                    }
                });

                var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
                service.getDistanceMatrix({
                    origins: [source],
                    destinations: [destination],
                    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
                    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
                    avoidHighways: false,
                    avoidTolls: false
                }, function (response, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK && response.rows[0].elements[0].status != "ZERO_RESULTS") {
                        var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
                        var duration = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text;



                        distancefinel = distance.split(" ");
                        //start_addressfinel = start_address.split(" ");
                    //  $('#distance').val(distancefinel[0]);
                        console.log(distancefinel[0]);


                        document.getElementById("distancesa").value = distancefinel[0];


                        ////////// IN THIS STATE I WANT DRAW LINE ///////////////////

                        /*

                        function poliLines(map, source_a, source_b, source_d, source_e){

                        var routes = [
                          new google.maps.LatLng(source_a, source_b)
                          ,new google.maps.LatLng(source_d, source_e)
                        ];

                        var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
                           path: routes
                           , map: map
                           , strokeColor: '#ff0000'
                           , strokeWeight: 5
                           , strokeOpacity: 0.5
                           , clickable: false
                       });
                */




                console.log(source);

                console.log(destination);

                var flightPlanCoordinates = [new google.maps.LatLng(source), new google.maps.LatLng(destination) ];
                var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
                    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                    strokeWeight: 2
                });

                flightPath.setMap(map);







                    } else {
                        alert("Unable to find the distance between selected locations");
                    }
                });
            } 
        );




    $('<div/>').addClass('centerMarker').appendTo(map.getDiv())
         //do something onclick
        .click(function(){
           var that=$(this);
           if(!that.data('win')){
            that.data('win',new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:'this is the center'}));
            that.data('win').bindTo('position',map,'center');
           }
           that.data('win').open(map);
        });
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: @Arthur Attout Can you help?

Comment: @ ArthurAttout  You have no comments?